# link to external stylesheet not working as expected in php include

Tags: php

So I've created this global header.php to use across my project, the links to my stylesheet folder is not working as expected when I call from another directory in my project.
Instead of the r_url() to return root_folder/stylesheet/..... it returns root_folder/public/index.ph/stylesheet/......

But when I run the header.php file itself, the code works fine, the r_url() function returns root_folder/stylesheet/...... as expected because the stylesheet folder is in the root_folder and the r_url() is supposed to return only the root_folder without any /public or whatever.

Please help.

Thank you.

```
//this is header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo r_url('/stylesheets/bootstrap-4.2.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
  <title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
```

```
<?php 

//This is initialize.php
//Assign file path to PHP constants
//__FILE__ returns the current path to this file
//direname returns the path to the parent directory
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public');
define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . '/shared');


 //this function is in another separate file
 //included here with "require_once"
function r_url($url){
    if($url[0] != '/'){
        $url = '/' . $url;
    }

    return WWW_ROOT . $url;
}

//create a constant to the project root directory
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public') + 16;

$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);


define('WWW_ROOT', $doc_root);


?>

///this is the index.php in my public folder that's giving me the problem
<?php 
require_once '../../private/initialize.php';
$page_title = 'Home';
include SHARED_PATH . '/header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: `WWW_ROOT` doesn't change when you're in the included file. It's still based on the URL of the original page, not the path to the include file.

Comment: Thanks for the response Barma. I'll try and see if I can fix it.

Comment: Easiest fix: Leave the WWW_ROOT out completely, and just use a URL relative to the domain root (so beginning with a `/`) to link to your stylesheet.